# onBackPressed and backStack showing blank screen before exit

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

Earlier, I was having an issue with onBackPressed and got it resolved with some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49968397/onbackpressed-not-following-backstack-goes-directly-to-home-fragment).

After doing some research, I found out that due to having my starting fragment in the backstack, it's producing an extra 'back' count so when I attempt to exit my app, I get a blank screen:

[image: Home / Starting fragment]
[image: After pressing back]

Instead of the blank screen I should get a prompt for "Are you sure to exit" instead of the blank. From the blank screen, I do get my 'are you sure to exit' menu, but I'd prefer not seeing an extra blank screen.

> I've also noticed that it seems to not update the fragment titles on the back pressed, but I'm assuming that's another issue all together.

**I'm unsure how to separate my home fragment from the backStack count. If I'm to avoid it from being added to the stack, but leave it as a navigational item, I'm confused on how that would even work.**

## Code:

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private Fragment fragment = null;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(Home.this);


    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
//        getHome();

    displayView(R.id.nav_large_monsters);

}

private boolean viewIsAtHome;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Pressing back popped the back stack, nothing else to do
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (!fragmentManager.isStateSaved() && fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()) {
        return;
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }

    if (!viewIsAtHome) {
            displayView(R.id.nav_large_monsters);
        } else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Home.this.finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
     }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void getHome(){
    fragment = new HomeFragment();
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentMgmt = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentMgmt.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    displayView(item.getItemId());
    return true;

}

public void displayView(int viewId) {

//        Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);

    switch (viewId) {
        default:
            fragment = new Large_Monsters();
            title  = "Large Monsters";
            break;

        case R.id.nav_large_monsters:
            fragment = new Large_Monsters();
            title  = "Large Monsters";
            viewIsAtHome = true;
            break;

        case R.id.nav_small_monsters:
            fragment = new Small_Monsters();
            title = "Small Monsters";
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;

        case R.id.nav_weapons:
            fragment = new Weapons();
            title = "Weapons";
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;

        case R.id.nav_armors:
            fragment = new Armors_Low_High();
            title = "Armor Sets";
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;

        case R.id.nav_charms:
            fragment = new Charms();
            title = "Charms";
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;

        case R.id.nav_items:
            fragment = new Items();
            title = "Items";
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;

        case R.id.palico_armor:
            fragment = new Palico_Armor();
            title = "Palico Armor";
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;

        case R.id.palico_gadgets:
            fragment = new Palico_Gadgets();
            title = "Palico Gadgets";
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;

        case R.id.palico_weps:
            fragment = new Palico_Weapons();
            title = "Palico Weapons";
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;

        case R.id.palico_helms:
            fragment = new Palico_Helms();
            title = "Palico Helmets";
            viewIsAtHome = false;
            break;

    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragment.getTag());
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
    }

    // set the toolbar title
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

}

}
```

Comment: Debug onbackpress method and see which line is executing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just don't have to call **addToBackStack(null)** on your Home page(ex: Large_Monsters fragment)

so just add in your **onCreate** method like this

```
Large_Monsters fragment = new Large_Monsters();

if (fragment != null) {
    FragmentManager fragmentMgmt = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentMgmt.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
}
```

In your left side menu, you just need to check whether this fragment exists or not, if not then replace it otherwise remove other fragments.

Comment: Thanks! This works a bit nicer than my workaround but both work about the same!

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out just after posting this...

The section here in the onBackPressed():

```
if (!viewIsAtHome) {
            displayView(R.id.nav_large_monsters);
        }
```

Was there to help set the check for what's the home page, but IF I use my getHome() method, and set that under OnCreate:

```
private void getHome(){
    fragment = new Large_Monsters();

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentMgmt = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentMgmt.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

This let's me set my home page, and avoids the double check at onBackPressed. But mainly, this avoids setting a check at my onNavigationItemSelected area and let's android handle onBackPressed as usual.